# How to compute curvature tensors for general n-dimensions?

Tags: differential-geometry

I keep coming across calculations like this,

Consider a metric on an $n+2$ dimensional manifold given as,

$ds^2 = 2dudr + 2L(u,r)du^2 -r^2d\Omega_n^2$

Then apparently once can write down the Ricci and Einstein and other tensors as a function of n.

Like for the above the Einstein tensor apparently has the following non-zero components,

$G_{01} = \frac{n}{r}L_r+\frac{n(n-1)(2L-1)}{2r^2}$

$G_{22} = (n-1)[(2L-1)(\frac{2-n}{2})-2rL_r]-r^2L_{rr}$

$G_{00} = -\frac{nL_u}{r} + \frac{2nLL_r}{r} + \frac{n(n-1)L(2L-1)}{r^2}$

and $G^2_2 = G^3_3 = ... = G^{n+1}_{n+1}$

(where the subscripts of L denote partial derivatives with respect to those variables)

For a fixed given n I can imagine doing the calculation either by hand or some software but I would like to know who these expressions are derived for a general n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given metric is in the form of a [warped product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warped_geometry), for which there are some well established methods of computing the curvature of the total space in terms of the curvature of the warp factors. See, for example, Barrett O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry*, Chapter 7. For the first factor (given by $u$ and $r$), it being two dimensional, you can just use the standard results for surfaces on its intrinsic curvature.

Answer (score 1):

The full solution to this problem (with a slight difference in notation) is given in appendix A: of the following  [article:](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/gr-qc/pdf/9910/9910109v2.pdf)